# Como trocar o último caractere em uma string?

Tags: javascript, string

Estou tendo um problema na hora de deixar o último valor nulo para ser inserido em um botão que irá apagar o valor que o usuário digitar, tentei usar o `for` para solucionar esse problema, mas não resolveu.

Alguém saberia dizer o que pode estar acontecendo?

```
for (var j = 0;j < getNum.length;j++) {
    if (getNum.length-1 == j) {
          getNum[j] = " ";
          alert(getNum[j]);
    }
    alert(getNum);
}
```

Comment: Você quer trocar todos os valores iguais ao que você quer? Por exemplo: Em uma palavra: Analfabeto; quero trocar todos os 'a'?

Comment: Tentou usar o str.replace('a','0')?

Comment: Não, na verdade só quero trocar o último valor, por exemplo: 123, quero que o 3 fique " ", e depois eu converto todo o valor pra um inteiro, no caso isso seria para ser incrementado em um botão para limpar o último digito do usuário.

Comment: Editei um pouco para ficar mais claro o meu problema.

Comment: Pode fazer assim: `const b = \`${a.slice(0, - 1)}_\``

Answer (score 6):

Se você já sabe qual índice quer (no caso, o último), não precisa fazer um `for` até chegar a ele, bastaria acessá-lo diretamente. Mas como a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/491199/112052) já disse, strings são imutáveis e não é possível alterá-las desta maneira.

Então uma alternativa é obter uma substring contendo todos os caracteres exceto o último, e concatenar com o caractere que você quer substituir:

```js
let str = 'abc';
// trocar o último caractere por espaço
let nova = str.slice(0, -1) + ' ';
console.log(`[${nova}]`); // imprimir entre colchetes para mostrar o espaço no final
```

No caso, `slice(0, -1)` pega toda a string do primeiro caractere (no índice zero), até o penúltimo (no caso, `-1` indica o último caractere, mas o índice final não é incluso no resultado, por isso ele vai até o penúltimo) - [veja a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) para mais detalhes.

---

O único porém é quando a string é vazia (`''`), pois neste caso o novo caractere é concatenado sempre. Mas se quiser, pode fazer esta verificação antes:

```
let nova;
if (str.length == 0) { // string vazia, não troca o caractere
    nova = '';
} else {
    nova = str.slice(0, -1) + ' ';
}
```

Comment: Ou pode-se usar o template string `\`${str.slice(0,-1)}_\``

Answer (score 5):

Primeiramente, se você só quer "trocar" o último valor da string, o `for` não é nem necessário. Seguindo a lógica do código da pergunta, poderia fazer assim:

```
getNum[getNum.length - 1] = " ";
```

No entanto, isso **não funciona** porque strings são **imutáveis** em JavaScript. Desse modo, você não consegue repor um caractere por seu índice dessa maneira (similar ao que se faz com arrays).

Você deve *criar* uma *nova* string. No seu caso, pode utilizar o método `String.prototype.replace` em conjunto com uma expressão regular para substituir o último caractere da string. Algo assim:

```js
const str = 'Foo Bar Baz';
const newStr = str.replace(/.$/, ' ');

console.log({ newStr });
```

A expressão regular que utilizei é bem simples:

```
.$
```

Ela basicamente selecionará qualquer caractere (`.`) que esteja ao final (`$`) da string. Saiba mais sobre o `replace` [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, resolveu aqui, só fiz um pequena alteração em const newStr = str.replace(/.$/, ' '); trocando ' ' por '', já que percebi que não podia ter espaço na hora que fosse carregar o comando outra vez, quanto ao link vou dar uma olhada, pois parece que tem muita coisa interessante.

Comment: @FabioLibonati então participe votando na resposta como correta ;-)